# Google Cloud Platform & Firebase - Cloud Scheduler Unauthenticated

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

Despite of setting permission `allUsers` with `invoke cloud function` role I'm not able to trigger scheduled cloud function due to error "unauthenticated".
Region is the same, tried to redeploy function few times.

What I can check for this issue?
This is fresh project.

This scheduled function was created using firebase tools

Comment: if I invoke this function manually, function works. I tried to redeploy this function with different name however no luck there.

Comment: I gave cloud functions admin to every possible service account and it still does not work

Comment: Does your default Cloud Scheduler service account have the Cloud Scheduler Service Agent role? Also, when you created the scheduled job, did you use the correct service account for `--oidc-service-account-email`? By default, Cloud Functions uses the App  Engine default service account.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Somehow it started to work after couple of hours without any changes with default roles.